# How to solve an equation with two variables in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

For example, I want to solve equation |x|+|y|=1 numerically, I would to get a rectangle. If I plot it out, it should be something like

[image: Rectangle]

It's a simple example. What I really want to solve is a equation like sin(x)sin(2y)+sin(y)sin(2x)=0.

Comment: Do you want to solve this numerically or symbolically? In the first case you can just 'try' a lot of values. In the second case you should look into `doc solve`. Either way, try a bit and show what you tried before posting here.

Comment: In addition to what @DennisJaheruddin said: Or, do you want a graphical solution?

Comment: Well, I want a graphical solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With your example equation, [Rody's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21116540/2586922) provides an analytic solution.

In general, however, given an equation f(x,y)=0 it may not be possible to find an analytic solution. In that case I suggest:

1. Define a target `x`, `y` area and generate random samples within it.
2. Compute `z = abs(f(x,y))` at the sample points.
3. Sort the values of `z` and define the approximate solution set as a given proportion of the lowest values.

   ```
   f = @(x,y) sin(x).*sin(2*y)+sin(y).*sin(2*x); %// your example function
   N = 1e7; %// number of samples
   proportion = 1e-2; %// choose to achieve thin lines in solution set
   xmin = -10; xmax = 10; %// x limits of target area
   ymin = -10; ymax = 10; %// y limits of target area

   x = xmin+(xmax-xmin)*rand(1,N);
   y = ymin+(ymax-ymin)*rand(1,N);
   z = abs(f(x,y));
   [zsort isort] = sort(z);
   n = round(N*proportion);
   plot(x(isort(1:n)),y(isort(1:n)),'b.','markersize',.1)
   axis square
   ```

[image]

Comment: +1, this'll do the trick. Unless of course you have one of those beautiful functions everybody always forgets about at first; for example, one that *increases* near the roots, decreases extremely rapidly in an extremely narrow region around the root and is only zero at *exactly* some value :)

Comment: @RodyOldenhuis Agree. Choosing the target region may also be tricky

Answer (score 5):

It really pays to do a little math before jumping to fancy graphs or numerical solvers.

Suppose you have

```
sin(x)·sin(2y) + sin(y)·sin(2x) = 0
```

From any [standard list of trig identities](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_trigonometric_identities#Double-angle.2C_triple-angle.2C_and_half-angle_formulae) you find that this can be re-written as

```
sin(x)·sin(y) · (cos(x) + cos(y)) = 0
```

So your equation holds when

```
  sin(x)·sin(y) = 0   or 
cos(x) + cos(y) = 0
```

in other words,

```
x = 0  ± k·π,  or
y = 0  ± k·π,  or
x = -y ± 2k·π
```

with `k` ∈ ℤ<sup>0</sup>.

Graphically, this would be a set of vertical lines (`x = 0 ± k·π`), a set of horizontal lines (`y = 0 ± k·π`) and a set of lines at ±45° (`y = -x ± 2k·π`).

Not a line of code needed.

Comment: Thanks for the nice analysis.